# How do I recursively iterate and edit a mixed variable containing arrays, classes and objects?

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am trying to use the RecursiveIteratorIterator Class and interate through every child object to see if certain keys match a specific list of columns I have.  Once the key/column matches, I will change the text.  However, I want to make sure I can access multi-dimensional arrays with objects in each element.

I'm looking to find a way to traverse the array and objects and then iterate through the lower child level and check the key name.  If the key name matches, I may want to run a callback function or some kind regex/replace function on it.

The data looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [01__BLAH_A] => 1
            [01__BLAH_B] => 0
            [01__BLAH_C] => 1
            [01__BLAH_D] => 1
            [01__BLAH_E] => 1
            [01__BLAH_F] => 1
            [01__BLAH_G] => 0
            [01__BLAH_H] => 3
            [01__BLAH_I] => 0
            [01__BLAH_J] => 1
            [01__BLAH_K] => 1
            [01__BLAH_L] => 1
            [01__BLAH_M] => 3
            [SOME_OBJECT] => some_object Object
            (
                    [variable_1:some_type:private] => 
                    [variable_2:some_type:private] => 
                    [my_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                            [BLAH_1_A] => nAME
                            [BLAH_1_B] => blahblah
                            [BLAH_1_C] => other_dude
                            [BLAH_1_D] => 1
                            [BLAH_1_E] => 55
                            [BLAH_1_F] => 1
                            [BLAH_1_G] => null
                            [BLAH_1_H] => 1234567989
                    )

            )
        [SOME_OTHER_OBJECT] => some_other_object Object
            (
                    [variable_1:some_type:private] => 
                    [variable_2:some_type:private] => 
                    [my_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                            [BLAH_2_A] => nAME of another
                            [BLAH_2_B] => fofofofo
                            [BLAH_2_C] => right_dude
                            [BLAH_2_D] => 1
                            [BLAH_2_E] => 33
                            [BLAH_2_F] => 2
                            [BLAH_2_G] => 0
                            [BLAH_2_H] => 987654321
                    )
            )
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [02__BLAH_A] => 1
            [02__BLAH_B] => 0
            [02__BLAH_C] => 1
            [02__BLAH_D] => 1
            [02__BLAH_E] => 1
            [02__BLAH_F] => 1
            [02__BLAH_G] => 0
            [02__BLAH_H] => 3
            [02__BLAH_I] => 0
            [02__BLAH_J] => 1
            [02__BLAH_K] => 1
            [02__BLAH_L] => 1
            [02__BLAH_M] => 3
            [SOME_OTHER_OBJECT] => some_other_object Object
            (
                    [variable_1:some_type:private] => 
                    [variable_2:some_type:private] => 
                    [my_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                            [BLAH_2_A] => nAME of another
                            [BLAH_2_B] => fofofofo
                            [BLAH_2_C] => right_dude
                            [BLAH_2_D] => 1
                            [BLAH_2_E] => 33
                            [BLAH_2_F] => 2
                            [BLAH_2_G] => 0
                            [BLAH_2_H] => 987654321
                    )
            )
        )
```

Notice that the data has a basic array of objects and some elements and nested objects.  THere may be different object types in each array element.  I want to have an iterator that is agnostic to all of these elements.

I thought I was heading down the right path with RecursiveIteratorIterator, but hit a roadblock when it got to those objects.

```
class Modifiable_Iterator
extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    private $char_set;
    private $columns_to_check = array();

    static function make($mixed_array_data)
    {
        return new self($mixed_array_data); 
    }

    function __construct($data)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($data), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST, 
            null);

        $this->columns_to_check = array('BLAH_2_A', 'BLAH_1_A');        
    }

    final public function current($parent_key_name = null)
    {
        // Retrieves the current value
        $current    = parent::current();

        if (in_array($this->key(), $this->columns_to_check))
        {
            // If the column name matches the list of columns in the private
            // variable, then edit the column value

            return _some_function_that_edits_this_value($current);
        }

        return $current;
    }

    final public function exec() 
    {
        $this->_loop_check($this);

        return $this;
    }

    final private function _loop_check($iterator)
    {
        while ($iterator->valid())
        {
            if ($iterator->hasChildren())
            {
                $this->_loop_check($iterator->getChildren());
            }

            $this->offsetSet($iterator->key(), $this->current());

            $iterator->next();
        }
    }    

    final private function _some_function_that_edits_this_value($value)
    {
        // Do something to the value and return it.

        return $value;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to take the mixed data object and then try to execute this code like this:

```
$new_text = Modifiable_Iterator::make($mixed_bag_of_data)->exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying with [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php):

```
class YourClass extends ArrayIterator{

    public function __construct($data)
    {

        parent::__construct($data);

        // your further logic

    }

}
```

Let's provide an instance filled with data:

```
$family = new YourClass(array(

        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Doe',
        'myAwesomeFriend' => new YourClass(array(

            'name' => 'Jane',
            'surname' => 'Doe'          

        ))

));
```

Now find a way to crawl this data:

```
// we search the $element for keys in $keyList, then call the $callback eventually
function map($callback, $element, $keyList){

    foreach($element as $key => &$value)
    {

        //if we need to iterate on the field, we do again
        if($value instanceof ArrayIterator)
            map($callback, $value, $keyList);

        // else if key is in given keylist, we apply callback
        else if( in_array( $key, $keyList) )
            $value = call_user_func($callback, $value);

    }

}
```

Using this function over `$family`, searching for key named `name` and turning value to lower case:

```
map(function($element){

    return strtolower($element);

}, $family, array('name'));
```

Let's have a peek at what `var_dump($family)` prints out:

```
object(YourClass)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayIterator":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "john"
    ["surname"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
    ["myAwesomeFriend"]=>
    object(YourClass)#2 (1) {
      ["storage":"ArrayIterator":private]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "jane"
        ["surname"]=>
        string(3) "Doe"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Case lowered, mission accomplished.

Caveat: your object / subobjects need to extend `ArrayIterator` - if you don't feel like that, you have to implement many of its interfaces [`Iterator`, `ArrayAccess`, and so] by hand.

Comment: the objects and subobjects won't be able to extend ArrayIterator as they are being passed in via other pre-defined functions.

Comment: After some testing, it seems like the ReflectionObject method worked like a charm.  However, the other "basic" array objects were edited but not saved when the data object was returned. The nested objects that were edited via Reflection were saved and returned. I have been using offsetSet() to set the other values.  The good news is, after I set it, I immediately print the value again using offsetGet(), and the value is correct.  However,the bad news is, when the Iterator returns the complete data array, the original values in the array sections are not set, but the objects are. HELP?

Comment: This is because objects are passed by reference, while arrays are by value - post your code, there will be a place to put a magical `&` that will solve your problem.

Comment: What do you of the code i updated in the post.  It was posted as another answer.  I can probably moved it to the original post ...

Comment: Frankly I don't know, it's a big wall of code - I think you'd better narrow down your constraints, i.e. if you just have to deal with arrays that **may** feature objects, but such objects haven't got further subobjects, the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is what I've come up with and it works for all of the objects, but not the individual array elements.  When I modify the objects using Reflection, the data is retained.

my current code snippet to execute this is still similar to my original concept:

```
Replacer::make($mixed_data_array)->exec();
```

And the code I've written is below.  For the most part, all of my nested objects are being altered as expected and returned to the $mixed_datay_array variable.  All of the other array elements that I am altering using the Iterators's offsetSet() method is not storing.  Not sure if I need to use the "magical &", which doesn't seem to fit in this scenario... or do I need to do another Reflection?   HELP!

(code below)

```
class Replacer
extends RecursiveIteratorIterator 
{
    private $char_set;
    private $char_set_exclude = array();
    private $columns_to_check = array();
    private $columns_with_titles = array();
    private $data;
    private $title_prefix;

    static function make($mixed_array_data)
    {
        return new self(
            is_null($mixed_array_data) ? array() : $mixed_array_data);
    }

    function __construct($data)
    {
        parent::__construct(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
                            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
                            null);

        $this->char_set = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                          . 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        $this->char_set_exclude =
            array('@',
                  ' ',
                  '.');

        $this->columns_to_check =
            array('email_address',
                  'member_name');

        $this->data = $data;
    }

    final public function replace_text($key, $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
            {
            return $value;
        }

        $new_text = null;

        if (in_array(strtolower($key), $this->columns_to_check))
        {
            $cypher = str_shuffle($this->char_set);

            // Each character in the string is replaced with shuffled text.
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i += 1)
            {
                if (in_array($value[ $i ], $this->char_set_exclude))
                {
                    $new_text .= $value[ $i ];
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_text .=
                        $cypher[strpos($this->char_set, $value[$i])];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $new_text = $value;
        }

        return $new_text;
    }

    final public function exec()
    {
        $this->rewind();

        if (!$this->valid())
        {
            return $this->process_child_object($this->data);
        }

        return $this->begin_replace($this)->get_data();
    }

    final public function get_data()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    final public function set_columns_to_check($columns_array)
    {
        if (!is_array($columns_array) && !empty($columns_array)
        {
            $columns_array = array($columns_array);
        }

        $this->columns_to_check = $columns_array;

        return $this;
    }

    final private function begin_replace($data)
    {
        while ($data->valid())
        {
            // If there are any child elements, repeat procedure for subobjects.
            if ($data->hasChildren())
            {
                $this->begin_replace($data->getChildren());
            }

            if (is_object($data->current()))
            {
            // If the current element is an object, process it 
                // differently: using Refelection

                $this->process_child_object($data->current());
            }
            else
            {
                // Used built-in offsetSet method to update the data keys if
                // the array element isn't in a private/protected object and
                // the key name is also in the columns_to_check array.

                $data->offsetSet(
                    $data->key(),
                    $this->replace_text($data->key(), $data->current()));
            }
            $data->next();
        }

        return $data;
    }

    final private function process_child_object($object)
    {
        if (!is_object($object))
        {
            return $object;
        }

        // Used Reflection Object and Property to make the data object
        // accessible for reading and updating.
        $ref_object = new ReflectionObject($object);

        foreach ($ref_object->getProperties(
                    ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED) as
                        $protected_property)
        {
            $data_array = array();

            $ref_prop = $ref_object->getProperty(
                            $protected_property->name);
            $ref_prop->setAccessible('true');

            foreach ($ref_prop->getValue($object) as
                         $key => $value)
            {
                $data_array[$key] = $this->replace_text($key, $value);
            }
            $ref_prop->setValue($object, $data_array);
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```